# VMware Player 7.1.4 unable to start services Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, kernel, vmware

I am trying to install and run VMware Player 7.1.4 on my Ubuntu 16.04 system. I downloaded the .bundle file and installed it by executing the .bundle file.

Upon launching VMware Player by typing `vmplayer` in the console this shows up
[image: When launching VMware Player]

Pressing Install gives this window

[image: Updater]

And finally this error pops up:

[image: Final error]

This is the output of the log file:

```
2018-01-16T19:05:38.347+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Log for VMware Workstation pid=22673 version=11.1.4 build=build-3848939 option=Release
2018-01-16T19:05:38.347+01:00| vthread-4| I120: The process is 64-bit.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.347+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2018-01-16T19:05:38.347+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Host is Linux 4.13.0-26-generic Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
2018-01-16T19:05:38.346+01:00| vthread-4| I120: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.346+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Msg_Reset:
2018-01-16T19:05:38.346+01:00| vthread-4| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.346+01:00| vthread-4| I120: ----------------------------------------
2018-01-16T19:05:38.346+01:00| vthread-4| I120: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.347+01:00| vthread-4| I120: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/home/rzmd/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.347+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Msg_Reset:
2018-01-16T19:05:38.347+01:00| vthread-4| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/home/rzmd/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.347+01:00| vthread-4| I120: ----------------------------------------
2018-01-16T19:05:38.347+01:00| vthread-4| I120: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /home/rzmd/.vmware/config. Using default values.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.347+01:00| vthread-4| I120: PREF Unable to check permissions for preferences file.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.347+01:00| vthread-4| I120: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/home/rzmd/.vmware/preferences": No such file or directory.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.347+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Msg_Reset:
2018-01-16T19:05:38.347+01:00| vthread-4| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/home/rzmd/.vmware/preferences": No such file or directory.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.347+01:00| vthread-4| I120: ----------------------------------------
2018-01-16T19:05:38.347+01:00| vthread-4| I120: PREF Failed to load user preferences.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.396+01:00| vthread-4| W110: Logging to /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-22673.log
2018-01-16T19:05:38.403+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.403+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Created new pathsHash.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.403+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Setting header path for 4.13.0-26-generic to "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include".
2018-01-16T19:05:38.403+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-16T19:05:38.404+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-01-16T19:05:38.404+01:00| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.404+01:00| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-01-16T19:05:38.409+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-16T19:05:38.409+01:00| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.13.0-26-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-01-16T19:05:38.559+01:00| vthread-4| I120: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/Module.symvers
2018-01-16T19:05:38.559+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.582+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Read 22181 symbol versions
2018-01-16T19:05:38.582+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Reading in info for the vmmon module.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.582+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Reading in info for the vmnet module.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.582+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Reading in info for the vmblock module.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.582+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Reading in info for the vmci module.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.582+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Reading in info for the vsock module.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.582+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Setting vsock to depend on vmci.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.582+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2018-01-16T19:05:38.584+01:00| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.584+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2018-01-16T19:05:38.585+01:00| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.585+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmblock".
2018-01-16T19:05:38.586+01:00| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.586+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmci".
2018-01-16T19:05:38.588+01:00| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.588+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vsock".
2018-01-16T19:05:38.589+01:00| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.604+01:00| vthread-4| I120: to be installed: vmmon status: 0
2018-01-16T19:05:38.604+01:00| vthread-4| I120: to be installed: vmnet status: 0
2018-01-16T19:05:38.622+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.622+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Setting header path for 4.13.0-26-generic to "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include".
2018-01-16T19:05:38.622+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-16T19:05:38.622+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-01-16T19:05:38.622+01:00| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.622+01:00| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-01-16T19:05:38.627+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-16T19:05:38.627+01:00| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.13.0-26-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-01-16T19:05:38.777+01:00| vthread-4| I120: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/Module.symvers
2018-01-16T19:05:38.777+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.799+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Read 22181 symbol versions
2018-01-16T19:05:38.800+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Kernel header path retrieved from FileEntry: /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include
2018-01-16T19:05:38.800+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Update kernel header path to /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include
2018-01-16T19:05:38.800+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-16T19:05:38.800+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-01-16T19:05:38.800+01:00| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.800+01:00| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-01-16T19:05:38.805+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-16T19:05:38.805+01:00| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.13.0-26-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-01-16T19:05:38.806+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Found compiler at "/usr/bin/gcc"
2018-01-16T19:05:38.809+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Got gcc version "5.4.0".
2018-01-16T19:05:38.809+01:00| vthread-4| I120: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.809+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Using user supplied compiler "/usr/bin/gcc".
2018-01-16T19:05:38.811+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Got gcc version "5.4.0".
2018-01-16T19:05:38.811+01:00| vthread-4| I120: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.814+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-16T19:05:38.814+01:00| vthread-4| I120: No matching PBM set was found for kernel "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-16T19:05:38.815+01:00| vthread-4| I120: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.815+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-16T19:05:38.815+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-01-16T19:05:38.815+01:00| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.815+01:00| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-01-16T19:05:38.820+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-16T19:05:38.820+01:00| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.13.0-26-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-01-16T19:05:38.821+01:00| vthread-4| I120: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.821+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-16T19:05:38.821+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-01-16T19:05:38.821+01:00| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.821+01:00| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-01-16T19:05:38.827+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-16T19:05:38.827+01:00| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.13.0-26-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-01-16T19:05:38.827+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2018-01-16T19:05:38.828+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.828+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Setting header path for 4.13.0-26-generic to "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include".
2018-01-16T19:05:38.828+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-16T19:05:38.828+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-01-16T19:05:38.828+01:00| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-01-16T19:05:38.828+01:00| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-01-16T19:05:38.833+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-16T19:05:38.833+01:00| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.13.0-26-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-01-16T19:05:38.983+01:00| vthread-4| I120: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/Module.symvers
2018-01-16T19:05:38.983+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2018-01-16T19:05:39.005+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Read 22181 symbol versions
2018-01-16T19:05:39.005+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2018-01-16T19:05:39.007+01:00| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-01-16T19:05:39.007+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2018-01-16T19:05:39.008+01:00| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-01-16T19:05:39.451+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Setting destination path for vmmon to "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/misc/vmmon.ko".
2018-01-16T19:05:39.451+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Extracting the vmmon source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar".
2018-01-16T19:05:39.457+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Successfully extracted the vmmon source.
2018-01-16T19:05:39.458+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-JgZWc7/vmmon-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2018-01-16T19:05:40.979+01:00| vthread-4| W110: Failed to build vmmon.  Failed to execute the build command.
2018-01-16T19:05:40.980+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Setting destination path for vmnet to "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/misc/vmnet.ko".
2018-01-16T19:05:40.980+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Extracting the vmnet source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar".
2018-01-16T19:05:40.985+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Successfully extracted the vmnet source.
2018-01-16T19:05:40.985+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-JgZWc7/vmnet-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2018-01-16T19:05:42.447+01:00| vthread-4| W110: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
```

Fixes I've found on the net and tried unsuccessfully are:

Reinstalling Linux headers (no change, headers were already installed, same behaviour of VMware)

Downloading and applying a patch from `http://pastie.org/pastes/9934018/download` (file not available anymore)

This blog post `https://dandar3.blogspot.se/2014/01/vmware-player-601-on-ubuntu-1404-alpha.html` (no difference)

My kernel is release 4.13.0-26-generic.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: A newer version of vmware player (current versions are 12 and 14) would have a better chance of working with a recent kernel like 4.13.